# How i can make Endless sliding of table content without white gap?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to make a sliding table that shows the rows from bottom to top contentiously without having a white gap at the beginning or end.

```js
var my_time;
$(document).ready(function() {



  setTimeout(function() {



  }, 200);




  pageScroll();
  $("#contain").mouseover(function() {

    clearTimeout(my_time);
  }).mouseout(function() {
    pageScroll();
  });
});

function pageScroll() {
  var objDiv = document.getElementById("contain");
  objDiv.scrollTop = objDiv.scrollTop + 1;
  $('p:nth-of-type(1)').html('scrollTop : ' + objDiv.scrollTop);
  $('p:nth-of-type(2)').html('scrollHeight : ' + objDiv.scrollHeight);
  if (objDiv.scrollTop == (objDiv.scrollHeight - 106)) {
    objDiv.scrollTop = -50;
  }
  my_time = setTimeout('pageScroll()', 25);
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: 'helvetica';
}

#contain {
  height: 100px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

#table_scroll {
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 100px;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

#table_scroll thead th {
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #ea922c;
  color: #fff;
}

#table_scroll tbody td {
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #ed3a86;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="CC">
  <table style="width:100%">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Phone</th>
        <th>Company</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
  </table>
  <div id="contain">
    <table border="0" id="table_scroll">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>User One</td>
          <td>0123456789</td>
          <td>Company1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>User Two</td>
          <td>000550050055</td>
          <td>Company2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Another User</td>
          <td>22221323123</td>
          <td>Company3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Some more users.............</td>
          <td>......................</td>
          <td>...............</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
  <p></p>
  <p></p>
</div>
```

Currently its working fine, but there is a gap, i want it to be one after another without starting from the bottom or top, like rotating a ball.

hope my question is clear.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi can you please create fiddle for better understanding

Comment: @Help . Hi!, thanks for quick response, here is the JFiddle link : [https://jsfiddle.net/gqf1La12/](https://jsfiddle.net/gqf1La12/)

Comment: @Titus , Thanks for editing, but that is not how i want it to look like, after the result goes up, there is a white empty space i want the first item to go to the bottom so its looks like endless items!.

Comment: I've just added "jQuery" after someone else created the snipped.

Comment: When i click on the fiddle, i cant see a white gap. It scrolls up and down all the time.

Comment: @DierigPatrick yes, thats the problem, i want it to move in one direction, like when the first items reaches the top it will go the bottom and keep moving to top until it reach the top again... and again ............

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used another example for a different customer. Maybe you can use it:

```js
/*
Ininite looping scroll.
Tested and works well in latest verions of Chrome, Safari and Firefox.

Not built/tested for mobile.
*/

'use strict';

var doc = window.document,
  context = doc.getElementsByClassName('js-loop')[0],
  clones = context.getElementsByClassName('is-clone'),
  disableScroll,
  scrollHeight,
  scrollPos,
  clonesHeight,
  i;

function getScrollPos() {
  return (context.pageYOffset || context.scrollTop) - (context.clientTop || 0);
}

function setScrollPos(pos) {
  context.scrollTop = pos;
}

function getClonesHeight() {
  clonesHeight = 0;
  i = 0;

  for (i; i < clones.length; i += 1) {
    clonesHeight = clonesHeight + clones[i].offsetHeight;
  }

  return clonesHeight;
}

function reCalc() {
  window.requestAnimationFrame(reCalc);
  scrollPos = getScrollPos();
  scrollHeight = context.scrollHeight;
  clonesHeight = getClonesHeight();

  if (scrollPos <= 0) {
    setScrollPos(1); // Scroll 1 pixel to allow upwards scrolling
  }
}

// Calculate variables
window.requestAnimationFrame(reCalc);

function scrollUpdate() {
  if (!disableScroll) {
    scrollPos = getScrollPos();

    if (clonesHeight + scrollPos >= scrollHeight) {
      // Scroll to the top when you’ve reached the bottom
      setScrollPos(1); // Scroll down 1 pixel to allow upwards scrolling
      disableScroll = true;
    } else if (scrollPos <= 0) {
      // Scroll to the bottom when you reach the top
      setScrollPos(scrollHeight - clonesHeight);
      disableScroll = true;
    }
  }

  if (disableScroll) {
    // Disable scroll-jumping for a short time to avoid flickering
    window.setTimeout(function () {
      disableScroll = false;
    }, 40);
  }
}

context.addEventListener('scroll', function () {
  window.requestAnimationFrame(scrollUpdate);
}, false);

window.addEventListener('resize', function () {
  window.requestAnimationFrame(reCalc);
}, false);





// Just for the demo: Center the middle block on page load
window.onload = function () {
  setScrollPos(Math.round(clones[0].getBoundingClientRect().top + getScrollPos() - (window.innerHeight - clones[0].offsetHeight) / 2));
};
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.Loop {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}

section {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  min-height: 300px;
  max-height: 700px;
  height: 80%;
}
.inner-wrap {
    animation: autoscroll 10s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes autoscroll {
  from { transform: translate3d(0,0,0); }
  to { transform: translate3d(0,-75%,0); }
}

::scrollbar {
  display: none;
}







body {
  font-family: "Avenir Next", Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 100%;
}

.red {
  background: #FF4136;
}
.green {
  background: #2ECC40;
}
.blue {
  background: #0074D9;
}
.orange {
  background: rebeccapurple;
}

h1 {
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 80px;
  letter-spacing: 5px;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<main class="Loop js-loop">
  <div class="inner-wrap">
    <section class="green">
      <h1>One</h1>
    </section>
    <section class="red">
      <h1>For</h1>
    </section>
    <section class="blue">
      <h1>All</h1>
    </section>
    <section class="orange">
      <h1>And</h1>
    </section>
    <section class="blue">
      <h1>All</h1>
    </section>
    <section class="red">
      <h1>For</h1>
    </section>

    <!--
    These blocks are the same as the first blocks to get that looping illusion going. You need to add clones to fill out a full viewport height.
    -->
    <section class="green is-clone">
      <h1>One</h1>
    </section>
    <section class="red is-clone">
      <h1>For</h1>
    </section>
  </div>
</main>
```